# GCC error when installing ncurses on OS X 10.8

Tags: gcc, makefile, ncurses

I'm trying to install [`ncurses`](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html) 5.9 on OS X 10.8 with GCC 4.9 installed. No errors or warnings show up when I run `./configure` in the `ncurses` directory, but when I run `make`, I get `gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-no-cpp-precomp’`. Upon googling the issue (and trying it out), I found that `--no-cpp-precomp` (with two dashes, i.e in long flag form) is a valid command.

I'm not sure what was prompting GCC to run the invalid command – whether it was `make`, or if it was a command specified in `ncurses` itself.

Is there any way to fix this? If so, how?

EDIT: I tried changing the reference in the `./configure` file from `-no-cpp-precomp` to `--no-cpp-precomp` manually, using a text editor, and was met with this, despite GCC seemingly accepting the `--no-cpp-precomp` option. After that, I tried running `autoreconf`, and got this:

```
configure:6558: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_DIVERT_HELP
      If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
      See the Autoconf documentation.
autoreconf: /opt/local/bin/autoconf failed with exit status: 1
```

After running it with the `m4_pattern_allow` option:

```
autoreconf: 'configure.ac' or 'configure.in' is required
```

After running `./configure && make` anyway:

```sh
cd man && make DESTDIR="" all
sh ./MKterminfo.sh ./terminfo.head ./../include/Caps ./terminfo.tail >terminfo.5
cd include && make DESTDIR="" all
cat curses.head >curses.h
AWK=gawk sh ./MKkey_defs.sh ./Caps >>curses.h
sh -c 'if test "chtype" = "cchar_t" ; then cat ./curses.wide >>curses.h ; fi'
cat ./curses.tail >>curses.h
gawk -f MKterm.h.awk ./Caps > term.h
sh ./edit_cfg.sh ../include/ncurses_cfg.h term.h
** edit: HAVE_TCGETATTR 1
** edit: HAVE_TERMIOS_H 1
** edit: HAVE_TERMIO_H 0
** edit: BROKEN_LINKER 0
cd ncurses && make DESTDIR="" all
gcc -o make_hash -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I../ncurses -I. -I./../include -I../include -DUSE_BUILD_CC -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I../ncurses -I.   -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -DNDEBUG -I. -I../include -I/usr/local/include/ncurses -O2 --param max-inline-insns-single=1200  --no-cpp-precomp ./tinfo/make_hash.c -Wl,-search_paths_first   
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘--no-cpp-precomp’
make[1]: *** [make_hash] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this has been fixed in the latest patches to ncurses 5.9

The 5.9 source can be found here: ftp://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-5.9.tar.gz

The latest patches are here: ftp://invisible-island.net/ncurses/5.9/ but the latest rollup patch appears to have the fix: ftp://invisible-island.net/ncurses/5.9/patch-5.9-20130504.sh.gz

To apply the patch, get the 2 files above then:

```
$ tar xvf ncurses-5.9.tar.gz
$ cd ncurses-5.9
$ gzip -dc ../patch-5.9-20130504.sh.gz | sh
```

Comment: I tried applying the patch to the files requested by the cmd line UI, but many of them failed ("incompatible versions") either partially or completely. Running `./configure` returns no errors, as before, and `make` returns the same error as before.

Comment: Updated my answer with the specific patch file and patching instructions.

Answer (score 0):

`--no-cpp-precomp` is an obsolete Apple GCC option it should generate a warnning not an error but if `-Werror` flag is passed to the compiler it will fail on warnings, either way, you will have to remove it manually from the build scripts and then run `autoreconf` or you could just remove it from the `configure` script directly.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Apple GCC" – I installed GCC from the source, downloaded directly from one of the mirrors offered on the GNU website.

Comment: in this case, I'm almost sure that `-Werror` is used, if you remove either flags from the configure script, it should work..

Comment: I've just tried all of that, and posted the result to my original question.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is very old now, but since I'm running into the same issue (need to build on Mac Yosemite 10.10 with GCC 4.9), maybe it'll help someone else too.  It looks like the configure script is detecting that it's a Mac and assuming clang is used, even though the 'gcc' from the PATH is GNU.  Seems they fixed the detection logic in newer versions.  I've found the same issue in Boost 1.37 and it was fixed (somewhere before) Boost 1.55.